# iOS imageData compression

Tags: ios, image-compression

I have an app and I need to compress images to max 10mb, I'm currently using:

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thePhoto2.image!, 0.9)
```

but it would be nice to get all my images in optimal quality.

Comment: Why are you passing 0.9 to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`?

Comment: isn't that making the file smaller?

Comment: So you want size, or quality?

Comment: i actually figured it out, but i wanted the files to be maximum 10mb, so some kind of kode witch would convert it to 10mb if it was larger than that